# Magento 2: System.xml checkboxes not saving values

Tags: magento2

I created a system.xml with a checkbox:

```
<field id="wedneday" translate="label" type="checkbox" sortOrder="23" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <comment>Wednesday</comment>
                </field>
```

But as soon as I click "Save config" the tick disappears and I cannot get the value. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The config section does not play well with checkboxes.
This is because you cannot set a value to the checkbox.
If you look in the dom you will see the attribute `value` for the checkbox to be empty.
So when you save it, Magento sees an empty value submitted and ignores it.
I suggest to take the easy way out and replace the checkbox with a `yes/no` dropdown. Magento supports this out of the box and you don't need to do much coding.

replace you code with this

```
<field id="wedneday" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="23" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <comment>Wednesday</comment>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

And you will see something like this:

[image]

There is a way to do it with checkboxes but you will have to create a frontend model for it. This involves a lot of code and the time needed to make it work is not justified since you have a  simple solution at hand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Am I wrong in thinking that Magento 1 had the checkboxes working out of the box with values "1" or "0"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add more info related to the checkbox type, as Magento manage it for you.

You should find this answer quite helpful [How to save Magento2 's type 'checkboxes' in admin form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117128/how-to-save-magento2-s-type-checkboxes-in-admin-form)